# What does the floating point arithmetic contribute to the rounding error in Mathematica?

Tags: computational-complexity, mathematica, floating-point

I am a theoretical mathematician who works on the iterative method to find some generalized inverse of my interest. When I have tried some numerical example in Mathematica $11.0$, this does not converge to what I have proved theoretically. I have convinced myself to some extend that this is because of the rounding error when you use floating point arithmetic.

I need a proper explanation with the proper reference to justify this.

> How does one theoretical mathematician should look into this and stop the discussion in his paper?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This beside what you asked, but have you only worked with machine precision or did you employ Mathematica's arbitrary precision numerics?

Comment: @halirutan I have worked with machine precision...

Comment: You can easily test your iteration with arbitrary precision. For reference, you could read the answers in [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/27505/187). Switching to arbitrary precision is simple. Even better would be using rationals and integers which are always infinitely precise, but I guess this is not an option if your method is moderately complex. Unfortunately, I cannot say more without knowing what you are dealing with.